# Can I configure uper version of OS as an Additional Domain Controller

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

I have two window server 2008 R2 domain controllers in my organization. I have installed a new IBM server with Server 2012 OS. Can I use this Server 2012 as an additional domain controller? If yes, what functional level shall I select on ADC (Server 2012) and if I raise functional level on ADC (Server 2012), will that raise on DC (Server 2008) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes however your functional level can only be as high as the lowest OS level. So in your case, you would continue to operate at the Windows Server 2008 R2 functional level.